# How to replace special characters in AWK

Tags: awk

I am trying to replace `../`  with null, but somehow it is not working, even though I have added escape character.

```
object_file_name = "c:/main/db/../../schema/schema_name/tables/dd3.tbl";
gsub(/"..\/"/, "", object_file_name); 
print object_file_name;
```

Output should be: `c:/main/db/schema/schema_name/tables/dd3.tbl`

Can someone advice?

Comment: When you say `trying to replace ../ with null` do you really just mean `trying to remove ../` or are you trying to replace it with a NUL character or something else?

Answer (score 0):

escape the dots too

```
$ echo "c:/main/db/../../schema/schema_name/tables/dd3.tbl" | awk 'gsub(/\/\.\./,"")'

c:/main/db/schema/schema_name/tables/dd3.tbl
```

Comment: yeah, I swapped the order, it can be the other way around too!  Since it's a repeat pattern doesn't matter for the end result.

Comment: ... unless it's a relative path: `../foo`.

Answer (score -1):

With `sed` you could:

```
$ echo "c:/main/db/../../schema/schema_name/tables/dd3.tbl" | sed 's/\.\.\///g'
c:/main/db/schema/schema_name/tables/dd3.tbl
```